# Azure Devops PipeLines .Net Website not copying bin folder

Tags: .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have my .Net website on Bitbucket and i was able to create a pipeline and release working on Azure devops. Everything works and all files get published to my Azure VM using webdeployment.
Only issue: bin folder with all dlls is not being generated (bin folder is not in Source control).
Any Idea?
[image]

Comment: More detail is required here.  Firstly, precisely what artifacts are getting published?  It'd be good to see the settings that you have for that.  Secondly, this is just the build step - where's the release pipeline that does the web deploy?  You should be able to view/inspect the artifacts produced by the pipeline, and verify that your files are all present - that way, you can determine if it's a packaging (build) problem, or a deployment problem

Comment: @BrendanGreen thanks for your comment, it is definitevely a build issue. When I inspect the artifacts all files are there but the Bin folder with the dlls. These are my build params: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"

Comment: as per my understanding I always include bin folder and in TFS, Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: my problem is that bin folder is created in the artifact but the updated build dll is not get complied by the TFS MS Build TASKS and not placed into the artifact, instead I manually I check Out the .dll file and than checkIn and after that my changes appears